# Why is this subset of $H^1_T$ not invariant under translation in time?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory, calculus-of-variations

I am reading the book of Mawhin and Willem on critical point theory and Hamiltonian systems and I am currently reading about functionals with symmetries. However, I am a bit puzzled about the invariance of some subset under a group representation. I will first provide the relevant definitions.

> Let $G$ be a topological group. A **representation** of $G$ over a Banach space $X$ is a family $\{T(g)\}_{g\in G}$ of linear operators $T(g):X\to X$ such that $$T(0)=\operatorname{Id},$$ $$T(g_1+g_2)=T(g_1)T(g_2),$$ $$(g, u)\mapsto T(g)u \text{ is continuous. }$$ A subset $A$ of $X$ is **invariant** (under the representation) if $T(g)A=A$ for all $g\in G$. A representation $\{T(g)\}_{g\in G}$ of $G$ over $X$ is **isometric** if $||T(g)u||=||u||$ for all $g\in G$ and all $u\in X$.

Now let us consider for some $T>0$ the Sobolev space $$H^1_T=\{u\in [H^1(0, T)]^3 : u(0)=u(T)\}$$ of $T$-periodic functions in $H^1$. We take the representation of $S^1$ given by translation in time, i.e. $$(T(\theta)u)(t)=u(t+\theta).$$
We have the following result about isometric representations of $S^1$:

> Let $\{T(\theta)\}_{\theta\in S^1}$ be an isometric representation of $S^1$ over $\mathbb{R}^N$ (with the Euclidean norm). Assume that $\operatorname{Fix}(S^1)=\{0\}$, where $$\operatorname{Fix}(S^1)=\{u\in \mathbb{R}^N : T(\theta)u=u, \forall \theta\in S^1\}.$$ Then $N$ must be even.

In our case, the representation is obviously isometric and the fixed points of the representation are the constant functions. Consider now the following subspace of $H^1_T$:
$$V:=\left\{a\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{T}\right)|a\in \mathbb{R}^3\right\}.$$ We have $\operatorname{dim}(V)=3$ and $V\cap \operatorname{Fix}(S^1)=\{0\}$. Now I believe that $V$ is invariant under the representation $\{T(\theta)|_V\}_{\theta\in S^1}$, but if this were the case then $\operatorname{dim}(V)$ would be even, which is not true. So, what am I missing, am I not reading the result I mentioned properly or is $V$ not invariant under translation in time?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the functional-analysis -side of the question, but two possible explanations occur to me. If $S^1$ acts as rotations about an axis $b\in\Bbb{R}^3$, then the 1-dimensional subspace spanned by multiples of $b$ consists of fixed points. On the other hand, if $S^1$ acts by translations in time: $t\mapsto t+u$, then the space $V$ is not acted upon. You would need
$$V=\left\{a_1 \cos(2\pi t/T)+a_2\sin(2\pi t/T)\mid a_1,a_2\in\Bbb{R}^3\right\}.$$
All because of $\cos(t+u)=\cos u\cos t-\sin u\sin t$, $\sin(t+u)=\sin u\cos t+\cos u\sin t$. Can't say for sure which it is :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for this comment, it really sheds some light upon my problem. The reason why I thought that my $V$ worked was because I thought that due to the periodicity of the cosine somehow I would get by translation just another cosine and that's it. I am not quite sure why this doesn't work (maybe because the $u$ in your example may not be some multiple of $2\pi/T$ and things don't add up nicely?), but I am glad to see that also adding in the $\sin(2\pi t/T)$ term to the space works and gives me a $6$-dimensional space, which is even dimensional.

Comment: After rereading your question I, too, started feeling that the latter possibility is more likely. Action of translation by $\theta$ takes $a \cos(2\pi t/T)$ to $a\cos(2\pi (t+\theta)/T$. The translation parameter $\theta$ takes values from a continuous set (otherwise we would not have action by $S^2$, and this brings the sine terms into $V$.